# power of point with circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a acute triangle and three altitude foot from $A,B,C$ are $D,E,F$ respectively. $H$ is the orthorcenter of triangle $ABC$. O is center of circumcircle of triangle $BHC$. Let $N=DF\cap BH, M=DE\cap CH$. Prove that $AO\perp MN$.

[image]

Here are what i did:

- Let $K=EF\cap MN$ and $L=AD\cap EF$, we have $(K,L,F,E)=-1$. Let $K'=EF\cap BC$ then $(K',L,E,F)=1$. Therefore $K\equiv K'$.
- O is a symmetrical to the  center of $(ABC)$ with respect to the straight line $BC$.

I'm stuck here. Somebody can help me!

Comment: You need to correct one M and add the O in the diagram.

Comment: Ok sir! I have corrected.

Comment: Why the circle around ABC?

Comment: Why this title ?

Comment: It is a problem in a document about power of point and radical axis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Therefore, why don't you attempt to use these notions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Hint: As shown in figure KC is radical axis of two circles. KA=KG are tangent on two circles(property of radical axis). You have to show that intersection of circles centers at Q and K intersect on MN that would mean $MN\bot AO$.

Comment: thank for your answer. This is a wonderful idea!